# Year wise cumsum based on condition on other column Python 3+ Pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cumsum

I have a dataframe with three columns as Year, Price, PV. I want a cumulative sum of column PV getting reset as per Year column, if values in Price column not equal to zero.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Year": [2000] * 3 + [2001] * 3,
                   "Value": [0,100,0,0,100,100],
                   "PV": [7,8,9,12,13,14],
                   'Cumsum':[0,15,0,0,25,39]})

print (df)
   Year  Value  PV  Cumsum
0  2000      0   7       0
1  2000    100   8      15
2  2000      0   9       0
3  2001      0  12       0
4  2001    100  13      25
5  2001    100  14      39
```

Comment: Don't post a screen. Use the actual table in your question directly. Use this site to do that: https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html):

```
df['Cumsum'] = np.where(df['Value'] == 0, 0, df.groupby('Year')['PV'].cumsum())
print (df)
   Year  Value  PV  Cumsum
0  2000      0   7       0
1  2000    100   8      15
2  2000      0   9       0
3  2001      0  12       0
4  2001    100  13      25
5  2001    100  14      39
```